# Null element of a binary operation

Tags: terminology

For a binary (commutative) operation $*$ over a set $S$ the identity element is an element $i\in S$ such that $$\bigl(\forall x\in\ S \bigr)\bigl(i*x=x\bigr)$$
Is it correct/common to call an element $a\in S$ such that
$$\bigl(\forall x\in\ S \bigr)\bigl(a*x=a\bigr)$$
the null element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more commonly known as an [*absorbing element*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element). The alternative name *zero element* is used when there is no confusion with some other kind of zero already present in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the zero element $0$ of a ring $R$ is absorbing, i.e., $r0 = 0 =0r$,
since $r0 = r(r+(-r)) = r^2 - r^2=0$. So maybe absorbing is the notion looked for here.